# C++ Bubble Sort Ascending order - does not sort all elements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I have to write a program which prompt the user for the number of integers to be read in. Then it prompts the user to enter these integers. Then it stores the integers into a vector and print the sorted values in ascending order from within a bubble sort procedure.
The problem in my program is that not all of the values in the vector are sorted properly. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    int nums;

    cout << "This program reads number of integers and store them into a vector."
        << "\nThen prints the values using Bubble Sort."; 
    cout << "\nEnter the size of the vector to be sorted using Bubble sort: ";
    cin >> nums;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        int number;
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> number;
        numbers.push_back(number);
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < (nums - 1); i++)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < nums; ++i)

            {
                for (int j = 0; j < (nums - j); ++j)
                    if (numbers[j]>numbers[j + 1]) // swapping element in if statement
                    {
                        int number = numbers[j];
                        numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                        numbers[j + 1] = number;
                        bool swap = true;
                    }
            }

        // Displaying the sorted list
        cout << "\nSorted list in ascending order using Bubble Sort:\n";

        for (int a = 0; a < nums; a++) //Use for loop to print the array
        {
            cout << numbers[a] << " ";
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For example I enter a 8 integers long vector and the numbers: 
43  6  23  1  75  34  98  76

The output is:
 1  6  23  43  75  35  98  76

So it looks like the numbers are stored properly half the way until the 5th integer.

Comment: `j < (nums - j)` Your innermost loop only looks at about half the elements, due to this bizarre condition.

Comment: Why do you have 2 for loops using i as an index?

Comment: The 2nd of the three nested `for` loops disregards the outer loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you so much! It should be j < (nums - i) . It's working now.

Comment: Just to make your exercise even more valuable and c++ish: You could try to implement a `bubble_sort`  function operating on `ForwardIterator`s and using a generic comparison.

Comment: Thank you Maikel, I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity I made an external bubbleSort function, here is the code. I hope it helps you understand how it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

void bubbleSort(vector<int>& arr)
{
    int n = arr.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n-i-1; ++j)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                std::swap(arr[j], arr[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numOfElements;
    cin >> numOfElements;
    vector<int> arr(numOfElements);
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements; ++i)
        cin >> arr[i];
    bubbleSort(arr);

    for(auto elem : arr)
        cout << elem << " ";
}
```